# How do i close file if I reach end of file c++

Tags: c++

For example -

```
std::string ans;
char b = 0;

void readtest(std::ifstream &file) {
    char a;
    while (true) {
        while (file.get(a)) {
            if (a == b) {
                ans += a;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (/*If it reaches end of file*/ false) { /*Here if it reaches end
                                                    of file i want to reset it*/
            if (!ans.empty()) {
                std::cout << ans << std::endl;
                ans = "";
            }
            if (b < 127) {
                b++;
            }
            else {
                b = 0;
            }
            file.close();
            file.open("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
    while (true) {
        readtest(file);
    }
}
```

Any idea how do I go about on closing and opening a file only if it has read until the end of the file. For example test.txt has abcdefg\0, once it reaches \0, close the file and open it again so it can start over from the beginning. I know the code is a bit long and might be complicated but thanks for reading.

Comment: `file.close()` ?

Comment: Do you really need to close the file, or do you just need to restart from the beginning? Also, files don't necessarily end in a null character.

Comment: All open file streams will be closed on program exit (and all memory will be freed, etc..), but build good habits early. If you open a file, then make sure you close it. If you allocate memory with `new`, make sure it is freed with `delete`. Good habits pay huge dividends as the size and complexity of your code grows.

Comment: Thanks, Fei Xiang never knew that. But yea i want to restart from the beginning(Only if it reached end of file), don't you do that by closing and reopening the file?

Comment: You don't have to. You can use [`seekg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). You can detect the end of the file by checking [`eof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) *after the read operation*.

Comment: Thank you so much David, I will keep that in mind. But because you see when the function ends, i don't want it to close the file and start from the beginning, so I want to keep it open until it reaches end of the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What's the point in manually closing a file if the destructor is going to close it immediately afterward?

Comment: So should it be something like if(file.seekg == std::ios_base::end) {close open}?, Fei Xiang.

Comment: @FeiXiang - nothing more than building good habits to help track the scope in which things are opened or allocated and ensuring they are closed/freed before the opportunity is lost. C++ is nice in that the files will be closed and containers (not manual allocations) will be freed if the refcount on the pointer is zero. But none of that is a substitute for learning when and how they should occur. Heaven forbid they actually move from C++ to C at some point.

Comment: No. `seekg()` *sets* the input position indicator, I know the name is confusing. The page I linked to has an example of using that to go back to the beginning of the file. Use `eof()` to check for the end of the file after the read operation, or you could just put the `get()` call in a condition like what you're doing now with the while loop.

Comment: @Kadhem your while-loop getting chars covers the case of failure to fetch another character. Eg. the if-test is pointless; you're at a state where you can't read anymore regardless. And frankly I'm trying to understand the point of the outer while-true loop , and struggling to see any reason behind it.

Comment: @Fei Xiang, nice get() worked, i tried >>, eof, peek != EOF and i did not think of trying get() lol. Thank you so much. You can post the answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin IMO the whole point of destructors closing files and smart pointers is that you don't have to manually do those things yourself. If you want to learn to "track the scope in which things are opened or allocated and ensuring they are closed/freed before the opportunity is lost", do so when you're learning about dynamic memory allocation, not with file streams.

Comment: @WhozCraig, once the function finds a character I want in the file. It returns, so how is the function supposed to be called again. I might make a for loop to loop 127 times through all the characters but why all the hassle making a for loop, when all i want is just to read the characters found on the command prompt.

Comment: @FeiXiang - sometimes I just shake my head when somebody says "don't learn how to do something." If the user wants to control when the file is closed, then there is nothing wrong with `file.close();` on a stream when you are done with it. Did I ever say you have to do it that way? No. The only thing I said was form good habits early. Sure, you can let the destructor close the stream and that is fine, that's part of understanding what happens. Equally valid is closing the stream with `.close()`. Why there is an argument about either point is a bit bewildering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the end of the file has been reached by checking [`eof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof), or the return value of the version of [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) that you're using. For example:

```
if (file.get(a))
{
    //read succeeded
}
else
{
    //read failed, potentially due to reaching the end of the file
}
```

Here, `get()` returns the stream, which when converted to a bool result in the value of `!fail()`.

To start reading from the beginning of the file again, use [`seekg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). Doing `file.seekg(0)` sets the input position indicator to 0, the beginning of the file.

You might need to clear the failure and EOF flags before you call `seekg()` using `file.clear()`.